# Badly Formed hexadecimal uuid string error in Django fixture

Tags: python, django

I have been doing this project I want to filter all_products by the category id name but when I do it, it gives me the badly formed hexadecimal UUID string error.
This is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    image = models.FileField(default=None)
    desc = models.TextField(default="Random")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    vnos = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.BigIntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    times_bought = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and views.py

```
def category_detail(request, category_id):
    try:
        current_category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Album does not exist.")
    current_category_name = current_category.category
    template = loader.get_template('categories/details.html')
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    products_by_category = Product.objects.all().filter(category=str(current_category_name))
    footer = loader.get_template('main/footer.html')
    head = loader. get_template('main/head.html')
    nav = loader.get_template('main/nav.html')
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(all_products, 6)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        all_products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        all_products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        all_products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'all_products': all_products,
        'all_categories': all_categories,
        'footer': footer,
        'head': head,
        'nav': nav,
        'products_by_category': products_by_category
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I have tried different methods but nothing really helps. I want to filter the products by the categories name when I click on a certain link.

The error is raised when I try to irritate over the variable.

```
{% for product in products_by_category %}
```

If I do not use filter on products_by_category it runs okay.

Comment: Note you should catch `Category.DoesNotExist:` when you try to fetch `Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)`.

Comment: Yeah that's a typo because I have one for the products but still big thanks

Answer (score 1):

When filtering the `Product` model by category, you should use the category instance, not the category name.

```
products_by_category = Product.objects.filter(category=current_category)
```

Note you don't need to call `all()` before `filter()`.

Comment: That's not the problem

Comment: I had to guess where the problem is, because you haven't included the full traceback in your question. That's the only place in the code where you call `filter()`, so what do you think the problem is if it's not here?

Comment: You are right but it gives me an error in the uuid not because i missed <code>all()</code>

Comment: I didn't say that you had to remove `all()`, just that you can remove it from the code because it's not needed. The error is because you trying to filter using `str(current_category_name)`, which is not a uuid. You should use `current_category` as I have above.

Comment: Thanks I think it actually fixed the problem